# Native App only or WebApp with Native App on top?

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, uiwebview

I want to build some kind of multi-user blog that should mainly be used via smartphone but CAN be used at a pc/mac too. I want it to be stored in the iOS and Android AppStores, so just a webapp with mobile-view option doesn't seem right to me. Now my question. Whats the best option to start with? Create the webapp first to get the backend, databases and stuff and than write the native app that gets access to that databases? Or start with native app first and just build a simple webapp that gets access to the native app backend? Or maybe write the webapp with mobile view option and just write a simple native app that uses the UIWebView to show the mobile version of my webbapp? I hope this question is not too confusing^^

P.S. I decided to go for ruby on rails for the webapp and store that stuff on amazon aws ;)
P.S.2 How much is the UI of a native app customizable e.g. TableViews etc? Because implementing WebApp via UIWebView may be the more stylish option?
greetz

Answer (score 0):

Look, Native UI will have quite good performance event on old Android devices,
but it requires some development effort to work with Android SDK. On another had you can create some hybrid webapp using Phonegap, but you shoud keep keep in mind that you may have some performance problems with slow-slow android's web view.

As for me blog app could be implemented with lightweight JS/HTML5, but in this case please don't use Jquery/ jQuery mobile - they are extremly slow, and I experienced huge performance degradation.

Comment: So it would be better to create a native app AND a webapp that just uses the same database? Let's take facebook as an example. The native app really much looks like the mobile view of facebook.com. did they just implement it or generated a whole new app? The listings of the statuses really much look like they are at the webpage. Is this look possible within a native app or is it just a WebView?